# DYLD_PRINT_STATISTICS not showing anything

Tags: ios, xcode, dynamic-linking, dyld

I'm trying to profile app startup after moving from static libraries to frameworks. We have 30 or so frameworks (fyi: cocoapods) so I want to check that it's not affecting performance. Anecdotal testing in the team says that it isn't, but I would like some numbers as well!

I've added the environment variables `DYLD_PRINT_STATISTICS` and `DYLD_PRINT_LIBRARIES` to see what the linker is doing, but all the output I get is from the `DYLD_PRINT_LIBRARIES` variable. I can see that the frameworks are loading correctly, but get no statistics from them.

I've tried restarting the device to make sure that the frameworks aren't in memory already but that hasn't helped.

Any other suggestions as to why I'm not getting any output from `DYLD_PRINT_STATISTICS`?

Comment: `DYLD_PRINT_STATISTICS` only seems to work on the simulator for me.

Comment: @RhythmicFistman I'm trying on the simulator :(

Comment: that's weird. what xcode version/sim version/sim device/deployment target? guessing now.

Comment: @RhythmicFistman Sigh, turns out I had the simulator running on my monitor but it was actually building to a real device I had plugged in; as soon as I unplugged it and actually targeted the simulator the output appeared :) If you move your comment to be an answer I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: thanks! I rounded the comment out with extra speculation

Comment: You are not running on the iPhone, useful in the simulator

Comment: Your iPhone system must be iOS 10

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While [other flags](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2239/_index.html), like `DYLD_PRINT_BINDINGS` work fine on the device, `DYLD_PRINT_STATISTICS` only seems to work on the simulator (for me, iOS 9.0).

In [this (possibly unrelated) version of dyld.cpp, from osx 10.10.5](https://opensource.apple.com/source/dyld/dyld-353.2.1/src/dyld.cpp) there doesn't seem to be any obvious exclusion of `DYLD_PRINT_STATISTICS` for devices, although there are conditionally compiled `TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR`s sprinkled throughout the code.

I guess it's a bug.

Comment: This now works on device as well since iOS 10. Highly recommend watching https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/406/

Comment: OMG!!! DYLD_PRINT_BINDINGS make console get crazy! console printing soooooooooo many log on my iPhone 5S (8.3) device...

Answer (score 13):

Looks like you can do it on device if you enable both environment variables in your scheme:

`DYLD_PRINT_APIS = YES
DYLD_PRINT_STATISTICS = YES`

Reference:
https://github.com/artsy/eigen/issues/586#issuecomment-118606377

Comment: This works now without adding the first variable i.e 'DYLD_PRINT_APIS' now. Apple mentioned they've improved this in WWDC 2016, https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/406/. Skip to 26:00. Tested on Xcode 9.1. Works perfectly fine. :)

Comment: On an iPhone 4S running iOS 9.3.5, `DYLD_PRINT_APIS` was the solution for me. `DYLD_PRINT_BINDINGS` as mentioned by @Meilbn will print so many stuff that I won't even get to actually launch the app after minutes of crazy logging.