# Invalid Bundle - App Store Rejection

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, carthage

I am trying to submit my app into the app store but I am getting an error message from Apple:

> Dear developer,
>
> We have discovered one or more issues with your recent delivery for
>   "My App". To process your delivery, the following issues must be
>   corrected:
>
> Invalid Bundle - One or more dynamic libraries that are referenced by
>   your app are not present in the dylib search path.
>
> Once these issues have been corrected, you can then redeliver the
>   corrected binary.
>
> Regards,
>
> The App Store team

I tried using this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38707387) to find out what's wrong but I am still stuck. I exported the iPA file of the app and used the `otool -L MyApp` command to find the frameworks. Here are the results:

[image]
[image]

These are my frameworks from the iPA file:

[image]

I downloaded all my frameworks using carthage and I added the frameworks to the embedded frameworks section:

[image]

However when I submit the app I get the same email back from Apple.

Thanks!

Comment: do you add all framework to CopyFile section in BuildPhase tab?

Comment: @Saeed-rz Yes I did

Comment: Version of IOS u are using?

Comment: Is there a case when you have added one framework and later you have removed it. But, that might be not removed properly.. 
Please Check header search paths in build settings..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got it accepted by switching "Always Embed Swift Standard Libraries" to yes:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this helps, but I encountered the same error once when updating an app. In that case, the problem was caused by a third party library that had to be updated to match the current set of architectures and SDK.

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion is open your `archieve` from `organizer` > see product folder > open project.app > see there should no any `.exe` file(any where within folders as well).