# Invalid Swift Support - The expected dylibs are missing from the app’s Framework location

Tags: ios, swift, xcode8, fastlane

I'm running fastlane beta to upload build to test flight.

What I'm getting after running lane beta-

Archive successful.
Successfully uploaded the new binary to iTunes Connect
Waiting for iTunes Connect to finish processing the new build
Build doesn't show up in the build list anymore, waiting for it to appear again..

I'm getting a mail from iTunes store-
Invalid Swift Support - The expected dylibs are missing from the app’s Framework location

-I have dylibs in my SwiftSupport folder.
-I'm giving archive_path in Gymfile where I'm copying the delis into my Framework folder before running pilot.
-configuration = Release
-ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES = YES

-fastlane version- 2.53.1
-Xcode version - 8.3.3

I wanted to ask what I'm doing wrong as this is not working. Is there an another way around? And can we copy files into the archive framework folder, after archive is successful.
I would want to know if someone else experienced this same issue as well.
I have seen similar questions related to dylibs but no one had the same issue.

Thanks in advance :)

(Important)- It's working fine when I'm archiving and uploading using Xcode.
The issue is when uploading with fastlane.

(UPDATE)- I'm getting the same with Xcode as well, archive and upload gets successful but then I'm getting the same invalid swift support mail from iTunes connect.

Comment: Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45879373/3411787)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to debug "Invalid Bundle" error which happens only after submitting to app store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38667492/how-to-debug-invalid-bundle-error-which-happens-only-after-submitting-to-app-s)

Comment: It's uploading fine with Xcode so I don't think adding custom framework will help. The issue is when I'm uploading using fastlane.

Comment: Are you using any pods/frameworks?

Comment: @ZaidPathan- Yes WebPDemux,Webp.framework,Fabric,Crashlytics.framework,QuartzCore,AVFoundation,OpenGLES,CoreVideo,CoreMedia.framework.
Pods- pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
  pod 'JPSVolumeButtonHandler'
  pod 'JKBigInteger', '~> 0.0.1'
  pod 'UXCam', '~> 2.5.8'

Comment: Ok Are they added to Embedded Binaries as well according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38667492/how-to-debug-invalid-bundle-error-which-happens-only-after-submitting-to-app-s/45879373#45879373)?

Comment: @ZaidPathan They were previously not added, but even after adding all the frameworks, I am still getting the same issue.