# XCode Project Invalid Bundle on App Store Upload

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, react-native, app-store-connect

When submitting our app to the app store the validation process for the build keeps getting rejected with the following error.

```
Invalid Bundle - One or more dynamic libraries that are referenced by your app are not present in the dylib search path.
```

Has anyone else had issues with this error?  I feel like I've tried just about everything.  I'd done the suggested `otool -L` on the main app as well as the watch app.  The only library that it shows linked for is the Mixpanel library.  The only other two libraries we are using is Fabric and Crashlytics.  From my understanding those are not actual real frameworks?  I've also tried to set `ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES` to `YES` as many posts online suggest.  The project builds and runs fine so I'm completely lost as to how to resolve this issue.

This is a React Native iOS app if that has anything to do with it.  I'm not the most experience when it comes to iOS stuff but I can find my way around xcode.  Anyone have any suggestions?  Maybe the best solution is to just create a new xcode project and set everything up again and copy/paste in the code from the previous project?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/38707387/4166688

Comment: @NiallKehoe Actually that did help!  I tried using the otool to find the missing libraries yesterday.  I ended up removing the libraries otool was showing as linked and relinking everything, and it worked!  Thanks

Comment: Will I add that as the answer