# Where to find missing framework files in React Native project?

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, build

I've pushed my React Native app to TestFlight and it's giving me an "Invalid Bundle - One or more dynamic libraries that are referenced by your app are not present in the dylib search path." error. I followed the advice in [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38667492/how-to-debug-invalid-bundle-error-which-happens-only-after-submitting-to-app-s) and used the `otool -L` command to display the components of my `.ipa` file. It showed me a list of frameworks, and the following ones do not exist on my system.

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/AssetsLibrary.framework/AssetsLibrary
/System/Library/Frameworks/AuthenticationServices.framework/AuthenticationServices
/System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
```

Does anyone know what I should do with this information?