# Find individual load time of Dynamic Libraries to identify which library consumes more time to load in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios9, libraries, ios10

The loading time of dynamic libraries has considerably increased causing a delay to the launch time of the app by several seconds. Though there are provision to load the libraries on need basis(lazy load), i would like to remove the most time-consuming library all together. which is the best approach to identify the load time of individual dynamic libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would look at `DYLD_PRINT_STATISTICS` as described [here](https://github.com/johnno1962/Accelerator). See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33776715/dyld-print-statistics-not-showing-anything) too.

Comment: this is not working now in xcode 14.2 any other way to get the same.

Comment: I don’t see a simple way to do this anymore. You might try Instruments. See https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/689581